# Which exponentiation algorithms do CPU/programming languages use?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, compiler-construction, cryptography

I've been learning about faster exponentiation algorithms (k-ary, sliding door etc.), and was wondering which ones are used in CPUs/programming languages? (I'm fuzzy on whether or not this happens in the CPU or through the compiler)

And just for kicks, which is the fastest?

Edit regarding the broadness: It's intentionally broad because I know there are a bunch of different techniques to do this. The checked answer had what I was looking for.

Comment: You can't reasonably ask about "which algorithm" when you're asking about different CPUs or programming languages. Maybe different systems use different algorithms. You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: @GregHewgill sorry, grammar mistake. I'm just looking for an example, like "x86 uses sliding door" or something.

Comment: In C/C++ math libraries, `pow(double,double)` and `pow(double,int)` are often different code paths, while `exp(double)` is yet another separate function. Which of these are you interested in? `pow(double,int)` often employs a variant of the square-and-multiply approach based on bit-wise scanning of the exponent. The old x87 FPU inside x86 processors has an `F2XM1` instruction that can be used to impement `exp()` and `pow()`. x86-based system usually use SSE instructions these days, the x87 FPU is mostly for legacy support. I can show code for `expf(float)` if that helps as an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I assume your interest is in implementation of the exponentiation functions that can be found in standard math libraries for HLLs, in particular C/C++. These include the functions `exp()`, `exp2()`, `exp10()`, and `pow()`, as well as single-precision counterparts `expf()`, `exp2f()`, `exp10f()`, and `powf()`.

The exponentiation methods you mention (such as k-ary, sliding window) are typically employed in cryptographic algorithms, such as RSA, which is exponentiation based. They are not typically used for the exponentiation functions provided via `math.h` or `cmath`. The implementation details for standard math functions like `exp()` differ, but a common scheme follows a three-step process:

1. reduction of the function argument to a primary approximation
   interval
2. approximation of a suitable base function on the primary approximation interval
3. mapping back the result for the primary interval to the entire range of the function

An auxiliary step is often the handling of special cases. These can pertain to special mathematical situations such as `log(0.0)`, or special floating-point operands such as NaN (Not a Number).

The C99 code for `expf(float)` below shows in exemplary fashion what those steps look like for a concrete example. The argument `a` is first split such that `exp(a)` = e<sup>r</sup> * 2<sup>i</sup>, where `i` is an integer and `r` is in [log(sqrt(0.5), log(sqrt(2.0)], the primary approximation interval. In the second step, we now approximate e<sup>r</sup> with a polynomial. Such approximations can be designed according to various design criteria such as minimizing absolute or relative error. The polynomial can be evaluated in various ways including Horner's scheme and Estrin's scheme.

The code below uses a very common approach by employing a minimax approximation, which minimizes the maximum error over the entire approximation interval. A standard algorithm for computing such approximations is the Remez algorithm. Evaluation is via Horner's scheme; the numerical accuracy of this evaluation is enhanced by the use of `fmaf()`.

This standard math function implements what is known as a fused multiply-add or FMA. This computes `a*b+c` using the full product `a*b` during addition and applying a single rounding at the end. On most modern hardware, such as GPUs, IBM Power CPUs, recent x86 processors (e.g. Haswell), recent ARM processors (as an optional extension), this maps straight to a hardware instruction. On platforms that lack such an instruction, `fmaf()` will map to fairly slow emulation code, in which case we would not want to use it if we are interested in performance.

The final computation is the multiplication by 2<sup>i</sup>, for which C and C++ provide the function `ldexp()`. In "industrial strength" library code one typically uses a machine-specific idiom here that takes advantage of the use of IEEE-754 binary arithmetic for `float`. Lastly, the code cleans up cases of overflow and underflow.

The x87 FPU inside x86 processors has an instruction `F2XM1` that computes 2<sup>x</sup>-1 on [-1,1]. This can be used for second step of the computation of `exp()` and `exp2()`. There is an instruction `FSCALE` which is used to multiply by2<sup>i</sup> in the third step. A common way of implementing `F2XM1` itself is as microcode that utilizes a rational or polynomial approximation. Note that the x87 FPU is maintained mostly for legacy support these days. On modern x86 platform libraries typically use pure software implementations based on SSE and algorithms similar to the one shown below. Some combine small tables with polynomial approximations.

`pow(x,y)` can be conceptually implemented as `exp(y*log(x))`, but this suffers from significant loss of accuracy when `x` is near unity and `y` in large in magnitude, as well as incorrect handling of numerous special cases specified in the C/C++ standards. One way to get around the accuracy issue is to compute `log(x)` and the product `y*log(x))` in some form of extended precision. The details would fill an entire, lengthy separate answer, and I do not have code handy to demonstrate it. In various C/C++ math libraries, `pow(double,int)` and `powf(float, int)` are computed by a separate code path that applies the "square-and-multiply" method with bit-wise scanning of the the binary representation of the integer exponent.

```c
#include <math.h> /* import fmaf(), ldexpf(), INFINITY */

/* Like rintf(), but -0.0f -> +0.0f, and |a| must be < 2**22 */
float quick_and_dirty_rintf (float a)
{
    const float cvt_magic = 0x1.800000p+23f;
    return (a + cvt_magic) - cvt_magic;
}

/* Approximate exp(a) on the interval [log(sqrt(0.5)), log(sqrt(2.0))]. */
float expf_poly (float a)
{ 
    float r;

    r =             0x1.694000p-10f;  // 1.37805939e-3
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.125edcp-07f); // 8.37312452e-3
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.555b5ap-05f); // 4.16695364e-2
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.555450p-03f); // 1.66664720e-1
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.fffff6p-02f); // 4.99999851e-1
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.000000p+00f); // 1.00000000e+0
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.000000p+00f); // 1.00000000e+0
    return r;
}

/* Approximate exp2() on interval [-0.5,+0.5] */
float exp2f_poly (float a)
{ 
    float r;

    r =             0x1.418000p-13f;  // 1.53303146e-4
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.5efa94p-10f); // 1.33887795e-3
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.3b2c6cp-07f); // 9.61833261e-3
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.c6af8ep-05f); // 5.55036329e-2
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.ebfbe0p-03f); // 2.40226507e-1
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.62e430p-01f); // 6.93147182e-1
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.000000p+00f); // 1.00000000e+0
    return r;
}

/* Approximate exp10(a) on [log(sqrt(0.5))/log(10), log(sqrt(2.0))/log(10)] */
float exp10f_poly (float a)
{ 
    float r;

    r =             0x1.a56000p-3f;  // 0.20574951
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.155aa8p-1f); // 0.54170728
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.2bda96p+0f); // 1.17130411
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.046facp+1f); // 2.03465796
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.53524ap+1f); // 2.65094876
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.26bb1cp+1f); // 2.30258512
    r = fmaf (r, a, 0x1.000000p+0f); // 1.00000000
    return r;
}

/* Compute exponential base e. Maximum ulp error = 0.86565 */
float my_expf (float a)
{
    float t, r;
    int i;

    t = a * 0x1.715476p+0f;            // 1/log(2); 1.442695
    t = quick_and_dirty_rintf (t);
    i = (int)t;
    r = fmaf (t, -0x1.62e400p-01f, a); // log_2_hi; -6.93145752e-1
    r = fmaf (t, -0x1.7f7d1cp-20f, r); // log_2_lo; -1.42860677e-6
    t = expf_poly (r);
    r = ldexpf (t, i);
    if (a < -105.0f) r = 0.0f;
    if (a >  105.0f) r = INFINITY;     // +INF
    return r;
}

/* Compute exponential base 2. Maximum ulp error = 0.86770 */
float my_exp2f (float a)
{
    float t, r;
    int i;

    t = quick_and_dirty_rintf (a);
    i = (int)t;
    r = a - t;
    t = exp2f_poly (r);
    r = ldexpf (t, i);
    if (a < -152.0f) r = 0.0f;
    if (a >  152.0f) r = INFINITY;     // +INF
    return r;
}

/* Compute exponential base 10. Maximum ulp error = 0.95588 */
float my_exp10f (float a)
{
    float r, t;
    int i;

    t = a * 0x1.a934f0p+1f;            // log2(10); 3.321928
    t = quick_and_dirty_rintf (t);
    i = (int)t;
    r = fmaf (t, -0x1.344140p-2f, a);  // log10(2)_hi // -3.01030159e-1
    r = fmaf (t, 0x1.5ec10cp-23f, r);  // log10(2)_lo //  1.63332601e-7
    t = exp10f_poly (r);
    r = ldexpf (t, i);
    if (a < -46.0f) r = 0.0f;
    if (a >  46.0f) r = INFINITY;      // +INF
    return r;
}

#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t float_as_uint32 (float a)
{
    uint32_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

float uint32_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint64_t double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

double floatUlpErr (float res, double ref)
{
    uint64_t i, j, err, refi;
    int expoRef;
    
    /* ulp error cannot be computed if either operand is NaN, infinity, zero */
    if (isnan (res) || isnan (ref) || isinf (res) || isinf (ref) ||
        (res == 0.0f) || (ref == 0.0f)) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    /* Convert the float result to an "extended float". This is like a float
       with 56 instead of 24 effective mantissa bits.
    */
    i = ((uint64_t)float_as_uint32(res)) << 32;
    /* Convert the double reference to an "extended float". If the reference is
       >= 2^129, we need to clamp to the maximum "extended float". If reference
       is < 2^-126, we need to denormalize because of the float types's limited
       exponent range.
    */
    refi = double_as_uint64(ref);
    expoRef = (int)(((refi >> 52) & 0x7ff) - 1023);
    if (expoRef >= 129) {
        j = 0x7fffffffffffffffULL;
    } else if (expoRef < -126) {
        j = ((refi << 11) | 0x8000000000000000ULL) >> 8;
        j = j >> (-(expoRef + 126));
    } else {
        j = ((refi << 11) & 0x7fffffffffffffffULL) >> 8;
        j = j | ((uint64_t)(expoRef + 127) << 55);
    }
    j = j | (refi & 0x8000000000000000ULL);
    err = (i < j) ? (j - i) : (i - j);
    return err / 4294967296.0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    double ref, ulp, maxulp;
    float arg, res, reff;
    uint32_t argi, resi, refi, diff, sumdiff;

    printf ("testing expf ...\n");
    argi = 0;
    sumdiff = 0;
    maxulp = 0;
    do {
        arg = uint32_as_float (argi);
        res = my_expf (arg);
        ref = exp ((double)arg);
        ulp = floatUlpErr (res, ref);
        if (ulp > maxulp) maxulp = ulp;
        reff = (float)ref;
        refi = float_as_uint32 (reff);
        resi = float_as_uint32 (res);
        diff = (resi < refi) ? (refi - resi) : (resi - refi);
        if (diff > 1) {
            printf ("!! expf: arg=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", argi, resi, refi);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            sumdiff += diff;
        }
        argi++;
    } while (argi);
    printf ("expf   maxulp=%.5f  sumdiff=%u\n", maxulp, sumdiff);
    
    printf ("testing exp2f ...\n");
    argi = 0;
    maxulp = 0;
    sumdiff = 0;
    do {
        arg = uint32_as_float (argi);
        res = my_exp2f (arg);
        ref = exp2 ((double)arg);
        ulp = floatUlpErr (res, ref);
        if (ulp > maxulp) maxulp = ulp;
        reff = (float)ref;
        refi = float_as_uint32 (reff);
        resi = float_as_uint32 (res);
        diff = (resi < refi) ? (refi - resi) : (resi - refi);
        if (diff > 1) {
            printf ("!! expf: arg=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", argi, resi, refi);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            sumdiff += diff;
        }
        argi++;
    } while (argi);
    printf ("exp2f  maxulp=%.5f  sumdiff=%u\n", maxulp, sumdiff);

    printf ("testing exp10f ...\n");
    argi = 0;
    maxulp = 0;
    sumdiff = 0;
    do {
        arg = uint32_as_float (argi);
        res = my_exp10f (arg);
        ref = exp10 ((double)arg);
        ulp = floatUlpErr (res, ref);
        if (ulp > maxulp) maxulp = ulp;
        reff = (float)ref;
        refi = float_as_uint32 (reff);
        resi = float_as_uint32 (res);
        diff = (resi < refi) ? (refi - resi) : (resi - refi);
        if (diff > 1) {
            printf ("!! expf: arg=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", argi, resi, refi);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        } else {
            sumdiff += diff;
        }
        argi++;
    } while (argi);
    printf ("exp10f maxulp=%.5f  sumdiff=%u\n", maxulp, sumdiff);
    

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```