# How can find out the contents of exp() built in function of the C numerics library of <cmath>

Tags: c++, function, cmath

I recently decided to build a simple calculator programme, but when it came to exponents i was lost. OK you can use , but i'd rather know how they solves the problem of that function, other than an impossible amount of if statements e.g.
    if(y==2){
    x=x*x;
    } 
    else if (y==3){
    x=x*x*x;
    }
And so on... So, how did 's exp() do it, and how can i find out?

Comment: @stark OK. if i delete this post, will my reputation be returned to the way it was before i asked? And also this is not a question of this is question of, trying to figure out.  how can i see the Exp() within the <cmath> preprocessing directory?

Comment: @NightHawk, You should be careful of deleting too many questions. Anyway, most of these major C standard library implementations are open-source. The case of an integer exponent could easily naively be done with a loop instead of tons of `if` statements, but `exp` handles fractional exponents.

Comment: You could look at the source code for open source libraries like [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html) or [fdlibm](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/). You can also see some worked examples in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381117/which-exponentiation-algorithms-do-cpu-programming-languages-use/29382053#29382053)

Comment: @chris, why what will happen if i delete to many questions, thanks for the genuine response, rather than youtube level mentality of some of your peers.

Comment: @NightHawk, I was thinking along the lines of [question bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), which include "a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts". I can't say that I know much of anything about how it works, though, including whether deleting many of your own posts contributes. My unreliable memory says that other users on the site have indicated that it can.

Comment: @stark I thought this was a factual site, is there room for insults as well?

Answer (score 1):

From [An algorithm for calculating exp(x) or e^x](http://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/algorithms.htm):

> An algorithm for calculating exp(x) or e^x
>
> This algorithm makes it possible for exp(x) or e^x to be calculated
>   using only the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and
>   division. The basic idea is to to use a polynomial approximation in
>   step 3 to calculate e^x. But because this approximation is only
>   accurate for small arguments x we must take steps 1 and 2 to reduce x
>   to a smaller value.
>
> 1. **Split up x:** Write x = n + r, where n is the
>      nearest integer to x and r is a real number between −½ and +½. Then e^x = e^n · e^r.
> 2. **Evaluate e^n:** Multiply the number e by itself n times. To 14 digits, e
>      = 2.7182818284590. The multiplication can be done quite efficiently. For example e 8 can be evaluated with just 3 multiplications if it is
>      written as (((e) 2 ) 2 ) 2. To further increase efficiency various
>      integer powers of e can be calculated once and stored in a lookup
>      table.
> 3. **Evaluate e^r using the polynomial:** EXP(r)=e^r=1 + r + (r^2)/2 + (r^3)/6 + (r^4)/24 + (r^5)/120
>
>    For r between −½ and +½ this polynomial is accurate to within
>      ±0.00003.

**EDIT**:

If you are interested in the original implementation in the GNU libc library then you can download the sources from [here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/).

Comment: Thank you. But is there a way of finding the exact contents of exp()? I know how exponents work.

Comment: @NightHawk I eddited my answer with a link to GNU libc library sources. you can find there the math library. Good luck.